# how to send iframe input values to parent using fancybox title

Tags: javascript, ajax, fancybox, fancybox-2

I tried to do it this way but got zero results:

```
    $(".fancybox-html").fancybox({
    type                : 'iframe',
    beforeLoad: function() {
        this.title = '<li onclick="parent.sendIframeDataToParent(document.getElementsByName(&quot;sector&quot;), &quot;sector_hook&quot;);">Submit</li>'
    }
});
```

and this is the code for the input in the iframe:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="contact" name="sector" value="cellular">
```

did I miss something?

Comment: I smell *same origin policy*

Comment: how can i access iframe dom?
this returns nothing:
    var chk = [];
      $("input:checkbox:checked").each(function() {
          chk.push($(this).val());
      });

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(".fancybox-html").fancybox({
      type : 'iframe',
      beforeShow : function(){
      contactChecked = $('.fancybox-iframe').contents().find('#contact').is(':checked');
    },
      afterClose: function(){
      //   The checkbox state is now available in the parent to do with as you wish
      alert(contactChecked); 
    }
});
```

Note: this will only work with Fancybox2.